# Scrollable tab bar in swift

Tags: swift, scroll, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm using a tab bar view controller with more than 5 items and it's showing as the fifth item an item named "More". I want to avoid that item and make the scrollable tab bar.
Thanks[Image](http://es.tinypic.com/r/21oy9gg/8)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can subclass UITabBar and get what you want.

You probably need to create this as a custom UI object. You could create it using a UIScrollview.

If you are a beginner then this is likely over your head.

Comment: Ok. I tried to add a UIViewController and a UITabBar embed in a UIScrollView but the scroll is not working properly. In fact, is not scrolling horizontally and the tab bar is not aligned with the top of the scrollview even when i add the constraint

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but maybe you could add a UIView to a Tab Bar Controllers scene (not the actual controller) and then add a UICollectionView on top of that same UIView of yours to create a custom Tab Bar. You would have to change the size and flow layout for the collection view but other than that if you are familiar with switch statements and delegates I don't see why it couldn't work!